# Android: How to create auto launch app at android startup for Kiosk mode

Tags: android, startup, kiosk-mode, device-owner

I have created the Kiosk mode app launched automatically at Android startup.
In order to auto start the app I used `BOOT_COMPLETED` service/broadcast.
But the app is started after 10-15 seconds from appearing HOME screen (Android).
This is not the state wanted by me. I want to will be started the app at same time to appear Home screen. So user can't any work without my app. This is my goal. My application is Device Owner app.

Is this possible? if so how? if not why?

Comment: You can set a Boot listener and start your app automatically when the device boots. But that wont really be *Kiosk Mode*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create an own home screen app called launcher. My manifest code is for launcher activity.

```
<activity android:name=".HomeActivity"
          android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
          android:stateNotNeeded="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This HomeActivity should be the first activity that is displayed when the device boots.

Comment: It is very simple. This is all what I wanted to know.

Comment: It is launcher sample. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2.git

Answer (score 0):

Using Device Owner, you can hide all the apps. setApplicationHidden

You can use startLockTask in your application to make it a kiosk app.

Documentation is available [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html).