# Starting kiosk application without any navigation bar or status bar while booting

Tags: java, android, android-launcher

I have an application for unattended use to develop on android device which needs to start when the device boots, now i have already created my app as an launcher but before my app starts i still can see navigation bar. In that moment when the nav bar is present user can still click on nav bar or pull the status bar down and make mess on the device.

Is there any programtical or configurational way to prevent any use until the launcher app starts ?

What i am trying to achieve is that ALL user interaction is disabled until the app is started, meaning not malicius intent from user is possible.

Are there any good aproaches for solving this?

With kind regards!

Comment: Ref https://github.com/jasondelport/AndroidKioskMode

Comment: @life888888 i know of immersive mode and i also override back and hide the nav and status bar, my app also starts when boot is completed, but the problem i have is that boot completed does not happen immediately and until the app receives boot completed nav and status bars are visible and user can in that short amount of time go into for example settings. I want to prevent interaction of nav and status bar from the start if that is possible.

Comment: Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37753464/android-how-to-create-auto-launch-app-at-android-startup-for-kiosk-mode , ＠user7716600 , `create an own home screen app called launcher` , `This HomeActivity should be the first activity that is displayed when the device boots.`

Comment: @life888888 thanks i will check it out. And write the results